# Creating dummy variables for a dataset

Tags: r

I am new to r and have a data set containing a column with 3 states (1,2,3). The problem is i dont know to split the data set with respective dummy variables as to create box plots and ultimately a linear model. 
   PLease help!! :'(

Comment: I would add a reproducible example and desired output if I were you...

Answer (score 1):

So I think you can specify which feature is categorical.
Say

```
data<- read.csv(filename)
data$feature <- factor(data$feature)
```

Where feature is the feature you want to convert to categorical data?

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not entirely , How would i group the data after that step to create 3 distinct box plots?

Comment: I assume that i will need to iterate the dataset with each factor in mind

Answer (score -2):

If I get your problem, you have 2 columns, one with factor levels (1, 2, 3) in your example, and another response variable. Is there it? (An example with part of your data would be very helpful). In any case, if your data has this structure you don't need to split it. For a boxplot just run

```
boxplot(data$variable~data$factor)
```

You can use the same approach for a linear model:

```
lm(data$variable~data$factor)
```

If your data has other structure, you will need to explain it before someone can give further help...

Comment: thanx for that but could you also assist me with finding the most appropriate model for daily rate , given this data set. [1]:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VOq-Dp4fS5xJ8LSfmkXw8VnHGs6Of9F9F6gxTVq0sPA/edit?usp=sharing